# How to retain selected text in JTextField when focus lost?

Tags: java, swing, selection, jtextfield, caret

Now finishing my custom menu popup, but the problem is that if I select some text in `JTextField` and click mouse button to show popup menu, then focus is transferred to popup window, AND selected text before are no longer highlighted. When focus is back to `JTextField` - selected text become highlighted again. How to make the selected text stay highlighted on focus lost?

Comment: please see [my question for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243101/how-to-override-defaultcaretsetblinkrate), better isn't it

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901833/text-selection-conflict-between-jtextpane-and-jtextfield/5911680#5911680

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> then focus is transferred to popup window, AND selected text before
>   are no longer highlighted. When focus is back to JTextField - selected
>   text become highlighted again. How to make the selected text stay
>   highlighted on focus lost?

- you can to override [DefaultCaret](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultCaret.html) for [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)
- you can to override [Highlighter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Highlighter.html)  for [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)

code example from DefaultCaret

```
class HighlightCaret extends DefaultCaret {

    private static final Highlighter.HighlightPainter unfocusedPainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.RED);
    private static final Highlighter.HighlightPainter focusedPainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.YELLOW);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean isFocused;

    @Override
    protected Highlighter.HighlightPainter getSelectionPainter() {
        return isFocused ? focusedPainter/*super.getSelectionPainter()*/ : unfocusedPainter;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelectionVisible(boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus != isFocused) {
            isFocused = hasFocus;
            super.setSelectionVisible(false);
            super.setSelectionVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

with output

[image]

from code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter;
import javax.swing.text.Highlighter;

public class TestTextComponents {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField jTextField1;
    private JTextField jTextField2;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Default Caret");

    public TestTextComponents() {
        jTextField1 = new JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new JTextField();
        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");
        jTextField2.setText("jTextField2");
        jTextField1.setCaret(new HighlightCaret());
        jTextField2.setCaret(new HighlightCaret());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(new JLabel("Please skip between text fields and watch persistent selection: "));
        frame.add(jTextField1);
        frame.add(jTextField2);
        frame.setTitle("Text component persistent selection");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTextComponents();
            }
        });
    }
}

class HighlightCaret extends DefaultCaret {

    private static final Highlighter.HighlightPainter unfocusedPainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.RED);
    private static final Highlighter.HighlightPainter focusedPainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.YELLOW);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean isFocused;

    @Override
    protected Highlighter.HighlightPainter getSelectionPainter() {
        setBlinkRate(500); // otherwise is disabled, stopped
        return isFocused ? focusedPainter/*super.getSelectionPainter()*/ : unfocusedPainter;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelectionVisible(boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus != isFocused) {
            isFocused = hasFocus;
            super.setSelectionVisible(false);
            super.setSelectionVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT have to restore [Caret.setBlinkRate(500);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultCaret.html#setBlinkRate%28int%29)

Comment: Wow, that simple, I'm impressed :) Thanks again indeed @mKorbel ! Problem solved in a few seconds :)

Comment: @Ernestas Gruodis glad if help you

Comment: After I set `textField.setCaret(new HighlightCaret());` I noticed that caret stops blinking.. Maybe there is some setting in `Caret` class? Now trying to dig deeper in `DefaultCaret` class.

Comment: Yes, like I expected - the `public HighlightCaret() {
            setBlinkRate(500);
        }` did the trick. Now caret blinks again :)

Comment: test whats returns getBlinkRate(), but AFAIK this could be another reason to use JTextPane, there is cursor visible

Comment: The caret was present, but didn't blink.

Comment: but hmmm now I see that Caret blinks on 3rd focusGained, no idea how to fix that

Comment: In the code above `setBlinkRate(500);` is placed in ` protected Highlighter.HighlightPainter getSelectionPainter()` method. I have place it in `HighlightCaret() { setBlinkRate(500); }`, so it is set only once. Not really understand what 3rd focusGained means..

Comment: got it, use most complete (you can to compare) [DefaultCaret](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5911680/714968) by @kleopatra

Comment: Found not much difference, except in `public void setSelectionVisible(boolean vis)` is `super.setSelectionVisible(!isSelectionVisible());`. Replaced it in my code, works the same, no problems.

Comment: well agree with you, but still I'm not satisfied, I made there important changes and change L&F to Nimbus, then caret blinkind on 3rd. focusGained

Comment: I always trying to create my own L&F - like this popup menu from scratch - so always independent from L&F - less problems.

Comment: It works almost... however, when I tab out of a component, it sometimes retains its yellow color. This is with default L&F (Metal). http://tinybrain.de/1008677 Same result with Substance L&F. http://tinybrain.de/1008678

Comment: Also I would love a solution where the selection is visible even when the text field has never been in focus (I preselect text through the program).