# How to highlight all the text in a JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, text, highlight, jtextpane

```
jTextPane1.selectAll();
```

With the correctly shared events, that command permit to highlight the text in a `JTextPane` area (I am a bit rusty, I need to not forget to share the "good event focus priorities" ; thank you to : MadProgrammer)

Comment: What happened when you tried it? `Highlighting not seem to appear in the jTextPane area` - What happened? Are you aware that by default a double click will highlight the current word? Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [`selectAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#selectAll%28%29) is a method of `JTextComponent`, which `JTextPane` extends from I would take a wild guess and say, probably, yes.

Five minutes of coding probably would have gotten you the same answer yourself...

> Highlighting not seem to appear in the jTextPane area (note : I use Java 7)

This is likely because the `JTextPane` doesn't have focus, try using `requestFocusInWindow` to bring keyboard focus back to the `JTextPane`.

The `JTextComponent`s don't always render selection highlighting when they don't have focus.

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestTextPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTextPane();
    }

    public TestTextPane() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
                JButton withFocus = new JButton("Select with focus");
                withFocus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        tp.selectAll();
                        tp.requestFocus();
                    }
                });
                JButton withOutFocus = new JButton("Select without focus");
                withFocus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        tp.selectAll();
                    }
                });


                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(tp));
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.add(withFocus);
                panel.add(withOutFocus);
                frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }        
}
```

You could also test it by using

```
textPane.selectAll();
System.out.println(textPane.getSelectedText());
```

For example...

**And now with double clicking**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestTextPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTextPane();
    }

    public TestTextPane() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                final JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
                JButton withFocus = new JButton("Select with focus");
                tp.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                            tp.selectAll();
                        }
                    }

                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(tp));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: **Yes it does** - when the component has focus, the selection will appear, when it doesn't it won't

Comment: `I have tried to get the focus by different ways` - Why are you trying to get focus? Your question states you looked for solutions using a mouse double click which means the text pane does have foccus. Post a proper SSCCE so we don't waste time guessing what you are doing!

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243101/how-to-override-defaultcaretsetblinkrate), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237317/how-to-retain-selected-text-in-jtextfield-when-focus-lost) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243101/how-to-override-defaultcaretsetblinkrate) which all discuss the problem...