# Unable to select "text with number and underscore" on DoubleClick in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, swingx, swingutilities

I have a text like, "test_1_another_2_test3" in my JTextPane. When I double click on the text, it does not select the whole text (sometimes, it selects only one character or number or the text between underscores). I can implement a mouseactionlistener, but have no idea how to implement the action.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624869/how-to-highlight-all-the-text-in-jtextpane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can implement a mouseactionlistener

You should not implement a MouseListener.

Swing works by using Actions. The `DefaultEditorKit` provides the default `Action` that selects the text on a double click.

See [Key Bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/). This class will show which `Actions` are mapped to a `KeyStroke` by default. It will also display all the default Actions for a component.

So basically you need to replace the default `Action`. The default Action is  called `DefaultWordActon`. This Action in turn calls `StartWordAction` and `EndWordAction`. It appears these two Actions stop searching when they find an underscore with a numeric value. So basically you need to modify this behaviour to keep searching.

The following code adds a loop to keep searching when an underscore is found:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class SelectWordAction extends TextAction
{
    public SelectWordAction()
    {
        super("Select Word");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JTextComponent target = getTextComponent(e);

        if (target != null)
        {
            int offset = target.getCaretPosition();
            beginWord(target, offset);
            endWord(target, offset);
        }
    }

    private void beginWord(JTextComponent target, int offset)
    {
        try
        {
            boolean keepSearching = true;
            int beginOffset = Utilities.getWordStart(target, offset);

            while (beginOffset > 1 && keepSearching)
            {
                String previousCharacter = target.getText(beginOffset - 1, 1);

                if ("_".equals(previousCharacter))
                    beginOffset = Utilities.getWordStart(target, beginOffset - 2);
                else
                    keepSearching = false;
            }

            target.setCaretPosition(beginOffset);
        }
        catch (BadLocationException bl)
        {
            UIManager.getLookAndFeel().provideErrorFeedback(target);
        }
    }

    private void endWord(JTextComponent target, int offset)
    {
        try
        {
            int length = target.getDocument().getLength() - 2;
            boolean keepSearching = true;
            int endOffset = Utilities.getWordEnd(target, offset);

            while (endOffset < length && keepSearching)
            {
                String nextCharacter = target.getText(endOffset, 1);

                if ("_".equals(nextCharacter))
                    endOffset = Utilities.getWordEnd(target, endOffset + 1);
                else
                    keepSearching = false;
            }

            target.moveCaretPosition(endOffset);
        }
        catch (BadLocationException bl)
        {
            UIManager.getLookAndFeel().provideErrorFeedback(target);
        }
    }


    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();

        Action action = new SelectWordAction();
        textPane.getActionMap().put("select-word", action);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new JScrollPane( textPane ) );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void selectAll() //method to select all Elements.
```

Selects all the text in the `JTextPane` ,but  it Does nothing on a `null` or `empty` document.

This method is inherited from `JTextComponent` Class, Which is a `super` class of `JTextPane`

> How To use this Method..

```
JTextPane obj_jTextPane = new JTextPane();
obj_jTextPane .selectAll();
```